# Two strings check true for equal but check false for Like operator

Tags: excel, vba, vb-like-operator

Why doesn't the "Like" statement work?

The "=" statement checks as true but the "like" operator checks as false, why?

```
Sub sandbox2()

Dim TagForm As String

TagForm = "tag(1###)<EX-->"

Debug.Print "Compare: " & Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value & " To: " & TagForm

If Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value = TagForm Then 'this works... displays message "Match!"
    MsgBox "Match!"
End If

If Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value Like TagForm Then 'this does not work... Does not display "Match!"
    MsgBox "Match!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry... cells(2,2).Value is "tag(1###)<EX-->"

Comment: `#` means a single digit when using `Like`.

Comment: # is a special character in the like operator and stands for any single digit. Hence the false value. Enclose them in brackets to escape their purpose

Comment: I know that... I don't understand why that would make it check as false?

Comment: Because the literal `#` is *not* a number.

Comment: To boil this down to a *very* small example and explain my previous comment a bit more, in the Immediate Window, `? "#" Like "#"`. The result is `False`. To get `True`, add brackets: `? "#" Like "[#]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the [Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) wrong. The `#` represents a single number digigt.

so you can compare the following:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
    a = "tag(1###)<EX-->"
    b = "tag(1###)<EX-->"
    c = "tag(1000)<EX-->"

    Debug.Print b = a       'true
    Debug.Print b Like a    'false

    Debug.Print c = a       'false
    Debug.Print c Like a    'trua
End Sub
```

If you compare `MyVar LIKE "tag(1###)<EX-->"` then
`MyVar` can be anything from `"tag(1000)<EX-->"` to `"tag(1999)<EX-->"`

Answer (score 1):

When using the `like` operator, `#` and `-` are both special characters.

To match the literal character `#`, add brackets around it, like `[#]`

See the full documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator